# Jquery date picker - setting the selected date format

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the `Jquery date picker` which is great but when I select a date the format of the date in the textbox is mm-dd-yyyy and I would like dd-mm-yyyy.

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

I have tried:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"});
```

but this does not change anything.

How do I get the correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/24SHu/)

Comment: Interestingly, I have now included a default date using <input type="date" name="startDate" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" id="datepicker" />. The default date appears as I would like in the input box, but when I open the date picker it takes this date as m/d/y and therefore opens the date picker on the wrong date. Any ideas?

Comment: just yy instead of yyyy